# PHP/Laravel Datetime Automatically Changes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have a code like below

**LocationController**

```
public function updateDriverLocation($id, $lat, $lng)
{
    $location = LocationModel::findOrFail($id);
    $location->lat = $lat;
    $location->lng = $lng;
    $location->last_updated_at = now();
    $location->save();

    TimeHelper::checkArrival($id, $lat, $lng, $location->last_updated_at);

    return $driverLocation;
}
```

**TimeHelper**

```
public static function checkArrival(int $id, $lat, $lng, $lastUpdatedAt)
{
    if (!$lat || !$lng) {
        return false;
    }

    if (strtotime(now()) - strtotime($lastUpdatedAt) > 900) {
        return false;
    }

    $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+ 9 hours"));

    ...
}
```

When `updateDriverLocation` is called, `now()` inside `LocationController` returns UTC time which aligns with server time, but inside `TimeHelper`, `now()` returns localized time. I want to know the reason why it does that. (It applies to php functions like `date()` and `strtotime()`, too)

I do have a lot of these like below in Base.php (And Every Model extends it).

```
public function get`some field name`Attribute($value)
{
     return $this->getLocalizedTime($value); // custom private function
}
```

As far as I understand, it should not affect the result above, because it should not only affect when data comes from database and this strange behavior even happens to php functions.

I want to know the reason for the behavior described above and also how to prevent that from happening. Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you're using the `Carbon::now()` function as `now()`?

Comment: On your LocationModel, do you happen to override the model's timezone with the protected $dateFormat variable in the class declarations? If so, this would obviously be the case. If not, maybe you can look at the store and update methods on the LocationModel to make sure that there isn't some sort of manipulation going on? Is the date being stored in the database as UTC or local timezone for that model?

Comment: @Chris Yes. I used `now()` in https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Carbon to work with dates in Laravel much easier.
[Carbon Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: `now()` returns Carbon object.

Answer (score 0):

As eResourcesInc in the comment, inside LocationModel I had some logic that overrides the UTC timezone with local timezone. So I have added a code that sets back to UTC timezone after whatever logic I had is done.